# Sibling divs match height in container

Tags: css

I have three divs in a container: http://jsfiddle.net/fBe9y/

One div has a lot of content. How do I get the other two `div`s, with less content, to match the height of the longest `div`?

I tried adding `height: 100%` to all the `div`s, but it doesn't work because that would need a `height` on `div.container`, which I don't know before rendering.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I recommend using `display: table-row;` and `display: table-cell;` for this. In short, what you do is make a table layout, but using `<div>` tags, and then style them to behave like a table.

This is better than just using a table for semantic and accessibility reasons.

But generally speaking, CSS does not give you many ways to refer to an element's siblings this way. The `<table>` tag does, but then it confuses screen readers and things.

If you wanted more rows, you would have more `.container` `<div>`s, and then create another `<div>` wrapping them all, and give it `display: table;`.

So with the same HTML you had, this CSS does what you want:

```
.container
{
    display: table-row;
}

.tile
{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid black;
}​
```

See **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fBe9y/7/)**.

Of note: while `display: table;` et al. are [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table), IE did not add support until version 8. If you plan on supporting this for IE 7 or lower, you'll be forced to use a more complicated approach, like [@Hristo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12716592/196921).

Comment: I did it with display: table at container only. and it works as well.

Comment: This answer is about 10 years old, and probably not the best solution anymore, now that flexbox is widely supported. Unless you need to support very old legacy browsers, I recommend using Twirlman's answer instead

Comment: @AlexvonBrandenfels Agreed, flex is the better solution for... almost all layout issues, really, these days. Though I don’t know why Twirlman has applied `display: flex;` to the tiles, or `flex-wrap: wrap;` to anything. Neither of those is required to achieve the desired layout unless I’m missing something.

Answer (score 20):

You can solve this using flexbox

```
.container{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tile{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Please note that not all browsers interpret the spec of Flexbox the same way. I've had troubles with this, see my example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34229644/microsoft-edge-flexbox-padding-behavior

Answer (score 8):

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1">1</div>
  <div id="div2">2</div>
  <div id="div3">3</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#div1 {
  display: flex;
}

#div2 {
  display: flex;
}

#div3 {
  display: flex;
}
```

this 'display: flex;' and 'align-items: stretch;' in the container should make all the children div same height, as long as it is of the desired height.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common question. Take a look at this article... it has all the answers:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Now, here's a quick fiddle of putting that to use. Try clicking on any of the "Column #" text elements to remove them from the document... the columns will resize nicely :)

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/qUT3d/9/

### HTML

```
<div id="container3">
    <div id="container2">
        <div id="container1">
            <div id="col1">Column 1</div>
            <div id="col2">Column 2</div>
            <div id="col3">Column 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#container3 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:green;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
#container2 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
    position:relative;
    right:30%;
}
#container1 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    right:40%;
}
#col1 {
    float:left;
    width:26%;
    position:relative;
    left:72%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#col2 {
    float:left;
    width:36%;
    position:relative;
    left:76%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#col3 {
    float:left;
    width:26%;
    position:relative;
    left:80%;
    overflow:hidden;
}​
```

Comment: That's the old method, and it was awful. CSS has evolved and has better tools than that now. The JS removal thing is pretty neat.

Comment: are you sure your `display: table-row;` and `display: table-cell;` solution is cross-browser compatible?

Comment: [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table) suggests that it's very-widely supported, yes. IE 7 and earlier did not support it, if that's a concern; that's a good point and I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: very cool! thanks for pointing this out to me :) I'll start answering similar questions in the future by providing both solutions